# Find the following one sided limits algebraically?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, limits, continuity

1. $$\lim_{x\to 1^+}\frac{\sqrt{2x}(x-1)}{|x-1|}$$
2. $$\lim_{x\to 1^-}\frac{\sqrt{2x}(x-1)}{|x-1|}$$

I know how to find one-sided limits graphically, but not algebraically. There's gonna be 1 answer for each problem, I believe.

Comment: Just notice that for the limit from the right you will have $x>1$ so that $|x-1|=x-1$. Then cancel to get $\sqrt{2x}$ and plug in $x=1$. For the limit from the left $x<1$ so that $|x-1|=-(x-1)$, and therefore the limit will have the opposte sign.

Comment: Follow smcc's clue for the right limit. Try to figure out the left limit on your own. You don't learn or develop understanding by having others do all the work for you, so I don't really like your last lines.

Comment: I saw that you posted a similar question a couple of hours ago, with several people providing direction, but you still seem lost.  If you have a sense of how to show this graphically, the algebra should fall into place.  What is happening at this limit point?  Can you break this into a two functions, that each describe the behavior on either side of this limit point?  And what are the limits of those functions?

Answer (score 3):

> There's gonna be 2 different answers of each problem, I believe.

No, each problem has only one answer.  Perhaps you're thinking of part of the process where you need to use the fact that $|x-1|$ is a piecewise function with two pieces, and the piece that you take depends on whether the limit is from the positive side $(x \to 1^+)$ or the negative side $(x\to1^-).$

Anyway, for the first one, we have $x \to 1^+$.  So $x$ is approaching $1$ from the positive side, which means we **always** have $x > 1$.  This is equivalent to saying we always have $x - 1 > 0.$  Consider then:

$$
|x-1| = \begin{cases} x-1, & x -1 \ge 0\\
 -(x-1), & x-1 < 0
\end{cases}
$$

This just follows directly from the definition of the absolute value function.  Before we can evaluate the limit, we need to know which piece we're on.  And we know we're on the first piece because, as we discussed in the previous paragraph, we know we always have $x -1 > 0$.  Therefore we're on the first piece.  So when we take the limit as $x \to 1^+$, the expression $|x-1|$ is really exactly the same as $x-1,$ precisely because $x-1 > 0.$  Then we have:
\begin{align}
  \lim_{x \to 1^+} \frac{\sqrt{2x} (x-1)}{|x-1|}
    &= \lim_{x \to 1^+} \frac{\sqrt{2x} (x-1)}{x-1}\\[0.3cm]
    &= \lim_{x \to 1^+} \sqrt{2x}\\[0.3cm]
    &= \sqrt{2}
\end{align}

I know you asked for both but if I fully explain both without you working it out then you won't learn it as well.  Try the other one on your own.  Big hint:  It's exactly the same except you use the other piece of $|x-1|$ and this leads to one very small change in the algebra in the end.

Answer (score 0):

1. $$\lim_{x\to 1^+}\frac{\sqrt{2x}(x-1)}{|x-1|} = \lim_{x-1\to 0^+}\sqrt{2x}\operatorname{sign}(x-1)$$
2. $$\lim_{x\to 1^-}\frac{\sqrt{2x}(x-1)}{|x-1|} = \lim_{x-1\to 0^-}\sqrt{2x}\operatorname{sign}(x-1)$$

Then notice that $\operatorname{sign}(x-1)$ is a constant ($\pm 1$) on the whole region $\mathbb R_{x\gtrless 1}$ -- may be extracted:

1. $$\lim_{x-1\to 0^+}\sqrt{2x}\operatorname{sign}(x-1) = +1\cdot\lim_{x-1\to 0^+}\sqrt{2x}$$
2. $$\lim_{x-1\to 0^-}\sqrt{2x}\operatorname{sign}(x-1) = -1\cdot\lim_{x-1\to 0^-}\sqrt{2x}$$

And the function $x\mapsto\sqrt{2x}$ is continuous near $1$ (by composition of continuous functions): so you can just strip the limit sign and substitute $x - 1 = 0$ ($x = 1$).

That should be pretty much algebraic :)
(maybe a better word is "formally")